# Android APK doesn't have the .so in the right directory

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries, android-ndk

I'm working on a relatively simple Android NDK project using Eclipse 3.6. I built my shared library with no problem and ndk-build put it in libs/armaebi (note: I didn't specifiy that directory in either my Android.mk or Application.mk files).  When I tried to run the project on the emulator, I got an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I then went through everything making sure I called System.loadlibrary, verified my header, etc. and everything looked OK. Finally, I noticed that logcat was saying it was looking for the file in ../lib *not* ../libs/armeabi. I then manually created a lib directory and put my .so in there, but still got the same error.  When I unzip the APK, I can see that Eclipse is still putting it in the ../lib/armaebi directory. I tried removing/adding the project, looking for a setting, etc. with no luck.

My question is: what the heck is going on?  Is this something really stupid? A setting somewhere that I just can't seem to find? Or is it somehow dependent on the API version? How does Eclipse decide what directory to put the .so in because it's clearly ignoring the structure I have in the project!

Thanks to all in advance.

-Pavel

Answer (score 1):

The Android package manager installs the library to lib/ rather than lib/armeabi, so there's no problem there. The armeabi is there in the APK because you can compile for either armeabi or armeabi-v7a and the package manager installs the most appropriate library for the device.

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is most likely due to an error in your JNI function signatures. You can check what the signature should be by running the compiled class file through the `javah` program. Any difference is the cause of the error.

Comment: Many thanks @richq.  I checked the .h and it matches the .cpp.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If you're using C++, you haven't got mangled symbols have you? They should be `extern "C"`, and make sure the C++ function names are correct for the Java class and method name where they are defined (unless you're using RegisterNatives).

Answer (score 1):

UnsatisfiedLinkError ,  can be possible due to platform compatibility missmatch. If you have compiled library for 2.2 version and trying to run on 2.1 device then this error may come. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another library your shared library links to? Android won't load dependent libraries for you; you have to do it in Java *before* the dependent library is loaded. Here's an example from my app that uses `NativeActivity`, but overrides it to load depended-upon libraries first:

```
package com.audia.dev.dummyandroid;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DummyAndroid extends NativeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //load libraries we depend on first
        System.loadLibrary("QtCore");
        System.loadLibrary("QtNetwork");
        System.loadLibrary("QtGui");
        System.loadLibrary("qtandroid");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

It might help to give the exact error from the logs.

Comment: This is not entirely true. ELF supports linking shared libraries with other shared libraries, and they are very well brought in by Android at runtime. In the case of Qt, the problem might be that the libraries don't link against each other or that the .so was not linked against all the libraries it uses. If you link your .so against QtCore, QtNetwork, QtGui and qtandroid, then all these should be loaded with the .so.